# Margin: auto doesn't work and other questions have not helped fix it

Tags: html, css, margin, centering

I'm having trouble getting columnContainer to center inside sectionTwo. The code is below. No matter what I do, it seems to be left aligned.

HTML:

```
<section class="sectionTwo">
        <div class="columnContainer">
            <div class="columnExplanation">
                <img src="Images/imagehere.png" style="width:150px;height:auto;margin-left:30%;margin-bottom:10px;"/>
                <p>text here.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
 </section>
```

CSS:

```
section.sectionTwo{

padding-bottom:20px;
width:100%;
height:340px;
position:relative;
background-color:#262626;
border-top: 8px solid #3C3C3C;
}

div.columnContainer{
width:100%;
position:relative;
display:block;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
margin-top:20px;
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: which element must be centered?

Comment: try this - http://jsfiddle.net/2hh286ys/

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to center 'ColumnContainer' it already centered it is because you have them both set to 100% width;

change it to this to see it actually working:

```
section.sectionTwo{

padding-bottom:20px;
width:100%;
height:340px;
position:relative;
background-color:#262626;
border-top: 8px solid #3C3C3C;
}

div.columnContainer{
background-color: red;
width:100%;
position:relative;
display:block;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
margin-top:20px;
text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: What's weird about when I make columnContainer less than 100% is that, instead of centering, it just indents over to the right 30 or 40 pixels...also, background-color: red; didn't work. Not sure why on that on either lol

Comment: What is it are you trying to achieve? I will mock it up for you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should use margin-left 30% on your image if you want to center it. Indeed, as an inline element, you can use text-align: center on your parent div to do the trick :

HTML:

```
<section class="sectionTwo">
        <div class="columnContainer">
            <div class="columnExplanation">
                <img src="Images/imagehere.png" style="width:150px;height:auto;margin-bottom:10px;"/>
                <p>text here.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
 </section>
```

CSS

```
section.sectionTwo{

padding-bottom:20px;
width:100%;
height:340px;
position:relative;
background-color:#262626;
border-top: 8px solid #3C3C3C;
}

div.columnContainer{
width:100%;
position:relative;
display:block;
margin-top:20px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Sorry about that, I mistyped. I am trying to center column container. Though I am also having trouble centering the image, and use the 30% as a temporary fix. I will try your text-align fix. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

this one will help you:

```
section {position:relative;}
section #your_id {
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    margin-top:-100px;  */half of your height*/
    right:50%;
    margin-right:-100px;  */half of your width*/
}
```